# WWDC Protocol-Oriented Programming in Swift session

Tags: swift, wwdc

What does this line of code from Apple's 2015 WWDC Protocol-Oriented Programming in Swift session do?

```
var draw: (CGContext)->() = { _ in () }
```

A Swift 2.1 version of the demo playground and file where this line of code is used can be found here: https://github.com/alskipp/Swift-Diagram-Playgrounds/blob/master/Crustacean.playground/Sources/CoreGraphicsDiagramView.swift

I am trying to understand how CGContextStrokePath(context) is getting called for all of the Drawables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a property with a closure (a function, or better: a code block, taking a `CGContext` as argument in this case). It does nothing. It ignores the `CGContext` (that's the `_ in` part).

Later in the example there's this function:

```
public func showCoreGraphicsDiagram(title: String, draw: (CGContext)->()) {
    let diagramView = CoreGraphicsDiagramView(frame: drawingArea)
    diagramView.draw = draw
    diagramView.setNeedsDisplay()
    XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = diagramView
}
```

where you can provide another closure `(CGContext) -> ()`, then this new closure is assigned to the `draw` property.

And in the `drawRect` function it's invoked: `draw(context)`.

So, basically you can provide a code block that draws something, for example

```
showCoreGraphicsDiagram("Diagram Title", draw: { context in
    // draw something using 'context'
})
```

or even shorter with the "trailing closure syntax":

```
showCoreGraphicsDiagram("Diagram Title") { context in
    // draw something using 'context'
}
```